# Calculate position change using the previous rows row_number value

Tags: row-number, sql-server-2017, recursive-cte

I'm trying to calculate the positional change based on the previous rows `ROW_NUMBER()` compared to the current `ROW_NUMBER()`

My query is using a recursive cte with a ROW_NUMBER() OVER .. clause which neatly gives me the row number of the result by its year.

```
WITH positions AS (
    SELECT 
        [incidents].state_id, [incidents].year_id, MAX(number_of_incidents) AS total_incidents_in_year,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [incidents].year_id ORDER BY MAX(number_of_incidents) DESC) AS position
    FROM
        [incidents]
    INNER JOIN
        years AS dy ON dy.year_id = [incidents].year_id
    INNER JOIN
        states AS ds on ds.state_id = [incidents].state_id
    GROUP BY
        [incidents].state_id, [incidents].year_id
)
```

After this my query then compares the positions to calculate the **change** between the row numbers.

```
SELECT
    ds.state_name, ds.state_id, [before].total_incidents_in_year, dy.year,
    [before].position AS before_position, [after].position AS after_position,
    ([before].position - [after].position) AS change
FROM
    positions AS [before]
LEFT JOIN 
    positions AS [after] ON [before].position = [after].position + 1 AND [before].state_id = [after].state_id AND [before].year_id = [after].year_id
INNER JOIN
    years AS dy ON dy.year_id = [before].year_id
INNER JOIN
    states AS ds on ds.state_id = [before].state_id
ORDER BY
    [before].year_id ASC, [before].total_incidents_in_year DESC
```

Unfortunately this does not work because the [after] position is always null.

This is a bit hard to explain so I've included a sqlfiddle link : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c7e57e/1

--

This image visually explains what I'm trying to achieve
[image: My envisioned output]

In 2011 Minnesota is in position 1, in 2012 Minnesota is in position 3, the change is +2

In 2011 Iowa is in position 6, in 2012 Iowa is in position 4, the change is -2

In 2011 South Dakota is in position 5, in 2012 South Dakota is in position 5, the change is 0

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

I was incorrectly trying to join on the ROW_NUMBER() which would result in a mismatch join because the row numbers would not necessarily line up correctly with the state id.

After changing it to join on the `year` which is the correct way of calculate a year on year change it all came together.

```
WITH positions AS (
    SELECT 
        [incidents].state_id, dy.year, MAX(number_of_incidents) AS total_incidents_in_year,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dy.year ORDER BY MAX(number_of_incidents) DESC) AS position
    FROM
        [incidents]
    INNER JOIN
        years AS dy ON dy.year_id = [incidents].year_id
    INNER JOIN
        states AS ds on ds.state_id = [incidents].state_id
    GROUP BY
        [incidents].state_id, dy.year
)
SELECT
    ds.state_name, ds.state_id, [before].total_incidents_in_year, dy.year,
    [before].position AS before_position,
    ([before].position - [after].position) AS change
FROM
    positions AS [before]
LEFT JOIN 
    positions AS [after] ON [before].state_id = [after].state_id AND [before].year = [after].year + 1
INNER JOIN
    years AS dy ON dy.year = [before].year
INNER JOIN
    states AS ds on ds.state_id = [before].state_id
ORDER BY
    [before].year ASC, [before].total_incidents_in_year DESC
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c7e57e/11